# How can one configure flask to be accessible via public IP interface?

Tags: python, flask, configuration, devserver

I am unable to resolve any methods externally via their url once I set the SERVER_NAME or host property in flask. The following is my app init config:

```
flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask.ext.cors import CORS
__authors__ = 'DarkStar1'

from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object('config')
app.config['DEBUG'] = True
app.config['SERVER_NAME'] = '0.0.0.0'
#app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
CORS(app)

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

from oms import user_service, person_service
```

I can set the DEBUG param/property but attempting to set the host or SERVER_NAME results in all urls, http://< hostname >:5000/test for example, resulting in 404s.
Since the server is a remote dev server, I am able to tunnel and get 200s on all urls from flask via localhost. The port is enabled and the flask version I am working with is 0.10.1 on python 2.7.6. I have search and read docs to no avail.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

run flask using

```
app.run(host="0.0.0.0:PORT#")
```

look for your IPv4 Address using `ifconfig` in your command prompt, and in your browser you can access your app using your ipaddress:port#

You might have to configure your router (port forwarding) to make it publicly available, otherwise you can
download/use https://ngrok.com/  ---->  This will expose your localhost behind a NaT or Firewall to the internet.

Once you download, you can configure it by running

```
ngrok http localhost:5000
```

this will provide you a RANDOMsubdomain.ngrok.io  and you can test your app from pretty much anywhere

Comment: run.app() or app.run()?

Comment: Got it up and running with app.run(host="0.0.0.0")

Comment: I had forgotten to add host and the quotes, thx

Comment: Even simpler, use `pyngrok` (`pip install pyngrok`) to invoke and manage `ngrok` right from within your `server.py`. [Here's a full Flask example](https://pyngrok.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integrations.html#flask), but basically you'd just need to `from pyngrok import ngrok` and then `ngrok.connect(5000)` when you're defining the routes.

Comment: nice, did not know of this.